# PDF Annotation property not changing properly

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, xfdf

I've manually created a PDF fillable form file and filled it out using an existing xfdf file.

When I try to do this programatically (creating the PDF fillable form on the fly to be filled out by existing xfdf), I notice that the properties of the field are "Visible but doesnt print".

When I compare this to the manually created PDF fillable form file, it has "Visible".

How can I programmatically set the generated field's property to "Visible"?

Is there something more I should add?

```
PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamper.Writer, false, false, 0);
            field.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(40, 500, 360, 530), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
            field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
            field.FieldName = "gender";
            stamper.AddAnnotation(field, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between

```
field.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT; //use this for "Visible"
```

and

```
field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT); // produces "Visible but doesnt print"
```